# c# Index was outside the bounds of the array (Probability for making a turn)

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to make a maze that is then run through by a computer by randomly picking a path, but I keep getting Index out of range errors, and I'm not sure why. I've looked at other posts, and it seems like it has something to do with the way that arrays are set up, but I can't figure out what is wrong in this code. This Line Has The Error:

Exception thrown: 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' in mazeai.exe

Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

```
if (popularity[turnNumber] > 500)
```

I was wondering how to fix the error, and if someone could tell me what caused it?
The Rest of the code is as follows

```
    static bool isDead = false;
    static int turnNumber = 0;
    static Random rand  = new Random();
    static int turnProb = rand.Next(1, 1001);
    static int turnDirection = 0;
    static int[] popularity = new int[10];
    static int[] turns = new int[10];
    static int[] maze = new int[10];

 public static void OpponetAI()
{
    if (popularity[turnNumber] > 500)
    {
        turnRight();
    }
    else { turnLeft(); }
}
```

Comment: Clearly `turnNumber` becomes larger than 9 at some point. We can't see where the int is incremented, though.

Comment: Check out your turnNumber value. For that error to occur, it must be > 9 or < 0 at the point of evaluation.

Comment: Seems more like a code review question than a common problem, the resolution of which wouldn't benefit anyone other than the asker.

Comment: Turn Number is added to when the turns are successful, and is always within the range of 0-9. I can post the rest of the important code if you need it.

Comment: Do `turnRight()` or `turnLeft()~ modify `turnNumber`?

Comment: "Turn Number is added to when the turns are successful, and is always within the range of 0-9." frankly, if you're getting the error there, it's probably not within your expected range...can't you just check the values on the IDE when it throws the exception? Assuming you're using VS?

Comment: Posting the rest of the code is the only way you'll get an answer, the code you've given doesn't show us anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add below checking to check the value of turnNumber.

```
public static void OpponetAI()
{
    if (popularity.Length <= turnNumber)
    {
        //add break point here, if you enter this break point,
        //then next "popularity[turnNumber]" will throw exception.
        //popularity only accept popularity[0] to popularity[popularity.Length-1]
    }

    if (popularity[turnNumber] > 500)
    {
        turnRight();
    }
    else { turnLeft(); }
}
```

Comment: It looks like that fixed it.